# detect number in a string - javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

how can i write a regex to find a phone number

this is a number 09876 09875

it should detect 09876 09875 as a whole number

this is a number +17865   8658 u98765

this should detect two numbers +17865 8658 and 98765

Comment: i am trying to detect phone number with spaces ,+ (,- signs in it

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: I'm still new to regex (hence not posting this as an answer), but could this do it? `[0-9\+\s]+`

Comment: Do you have correct inputs and just want to extract the number groups or do you want to test if a given input contains a valid phone number according to your specs?

Comment: yes trying to test the given input and test if it is valid phone number with above rules

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces and match plus sign with following numbers:

```
var input   = 'this is a number +17865 8658 u98765',
    outputs = input.replace(/ /g, '').match(/\+?\d+/g);
```

Output:

```
["+178658658", "98765"]
```

Without replacing spaces:

```
var input   = 'this is a number +17865 8658 u98765',
    outputs = input.match(/\+?\d( *\d+)+/g);
```

Output:

```
["+17865 8658", "98765"]
```

Comment: i do not want to remove spaces keep them as they are like if the number is +16786 876 986  it should detect it  but if the number is +1234 u89 97  it should detect two number +1234 and 89 97

Comment: it should detect this number a whole number +123 456 788 not as three separate numbers

Answer (score 1):

Use following Regex

```
/[+0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?/g
```

[for working example click](http://regexr.com?346c7)

Comment: close , but it does not detect +198-9876 (76569) (876 8)

Comment: it should detect this number a whole number  +123 456 788  not as three separate numbers